# accessing Unicode properties from Python

Tags: python, python-unicode

Is there a simple method in Python to determine whether a given Unicode character has a specific property (not sure that I have the right terminology there) as given by http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropList.txt, such as "Ideographic"?

I've looked in `unicodedata` and `str` but don't know where else to look. I know how to use `unicodedata.category` but that's a different kind of classification than what I need.

Comment: I guess you have to parse the list into a useful data structure and work with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unicode table information about a character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058402/unicode-table-information-about-a-character-in-python)