# Is there a way to list all the characters and names in unicodedata?

Tags: python, python-unicode

I can use `unicodedata.name()` and `unicodedata.lookup()` map between characters and their names. But it must be one at a time.

Is there an easy way to get the mapping of all the characters? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unicode table information about a character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058402/unicode-table-information-about-a-character-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no builtin mapping of all the characters. But you can generate you own easily:

```
import pandas as pd
mapping = pd.DataFrame({'nums': list(range(0, 0x110000)),
                        'chars': list(map(chr, range(0, 0x110000)))})
```

Comment: Why end at 11001? There are many more code points in Unicode.

Comment: Good point, it was an arbitrary choice. I've updated the code to give the whole range.