# How to retrieve unicode category of a character in dart?

Tags: dart, unicode

In python there is a **unicode** library to get information about the category of a character.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html?#unicodedata.category

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48060112/579689

Is there a similar method to retrieve the category information of a unicode character in dart?